# My Flutter app keeps crashing on iOS, but it works in the Android simulator

Tags: flutter, xcode, crash

I get an error in a file called *FLTAdUtil* and the *google-mobile-ads* package saying that pointer is missing a nullability type. I am not sure as I have uploaded my app to [Google Play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play), and it works. And on my Mac I used the Android simulator, and it also worked.

```dart
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface FLTAdUtil : NSObject

+ (BOOL)isNull:(id)object;

+ (BOOL)isNotNull:(id)object;

+ (WKWebView *_Nullable)getWebView:(NSNumber *_Nonnull)webViewId
             flutterPluginRegistry:
                 (id<FlutterPluginRegistry> _Nonnull)flutterPluginRegistry;

@property(readonly, class) NSString *requestAgent;

@end
```

Comment: Re *"My Flutter app keeps crashing on iOS"*: Is that code in [Dart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dart_(programming_language)#Example)? Or in [Objective-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C)? Or in something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not know the concept of keys existed for IOS development.
Opened the infoplist file and did my magic

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).